# code view during debugging

Tags: debugging, swift2, xcode7

when setting a breakpoint in my swift file, I alway only get the assembly code view, similar to:

```
0x677dc <+508>:   movl   -0x3c0(%ebp), %esi
0x677e2 <+514>:   movl   %esi, 0xc(%esp)
0x677e6 <+518>:   movl   %eax, 0x10(%esp)
0x677ea <+522>:   movl   %edx, 0x14(%esp)
0x677ee <+526>:   movl   %ecx, 0x18(%esp)
0x677f2 <+530>:   calll  0x825f4                   ; symbol stub for:
```

I can no further step through my Swift code. It does not matter where in the swift code I set the breakpoint (or in which file), view is always on this level of detail. How do I switch back to "normal" swift code view whilst debugging / stepping through code? (am using Swift 2.0 in Xcode 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting to switch the assembly code view off is:

Debug > Debug Workflow > Always Show Disassembly

(still have no idea though why this was suddenly switched on)